# PowerBI: How to display a detail data on a second page after clicking on a row in a Matrix?

Tags: sql, powerbi, analysis

I am very new to PowerBI.

I have displayed a table of data using Matrix but want to show details of additional data upon clicking one of the rows. It can be displayed on the second page.

I wonder if it's possible and can someine direct me to what the process is?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the drill-through feature provided by Power BI. If you don't already know how it works, this [post](http://radacad.com/master-detail-design-with-drillthrough-filter-in-power-bi) has the exact thing you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).